# Cannot load configuration class: org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I am building Spring Boot + MyBatis + MySQL , I have added the configurations into pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 添加 MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.41</version>
    </dependency>
```

my main function is like this:

```
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication
 public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
 }
```

but when I run the main function, I get the following Exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:458) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:400) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

I don't know where I am wrong, mybatis-spring version is 1.3.2, maven version is 3.3.9 , mybatis version. Is 3.4.6 is there something wrong with my version?

Answer (score 0):

You should update spring boot version above

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

- Please refer below article

  - https://www.itread01.com/content/1549718835.html